# What is this widget called (if it exists)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iW8ha.png)

is this a widget you can use in tkinter and if so what is it called? i see it on many different pieces of software such as task manager (as seen in the picture), OpenRGB and others. thanks in advance

Comment: Are you referring to "tabs"?

Comment: That looks like the [notebook](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html) option.

Answer (score 1):

this widget is called a Notebook. A notebook is a widget that contains multiple frames that are accessible by tab buttons. It is created like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

#This is the notebook widget
nb = ttk.Notebook(root)
nb.pack(pady=10, expand=True)

#Creating frames for the notebook
frame1 = tk.Frame(nb)
frame1.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

frame2 = tk.Frame(nb)
frame2.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

frame3 = tk.Frame(nb)
frame3.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

#Adding the frames to the notebook
nb.add(frame1, text='tab_name')    
nb.add(frame2, text='tab_name')   
nb.add(frame3, text='tab_name')
```